# Translate Image to Byte[]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am looking for a method to transform a BitmapImage into a byte[] in c# .

Let's say that I have those two variables :

```
byte[] ByteArray; 
BitmapImage TheImage;
```

How can I make

```
ByteArray = TheImage
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: In what way do you want to transform the image into a byte array? For example, do you want it in an image format (e.g. JPEG) or do you want the raw color information from the image pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SaveJpeg` method of `WriteableBitmap`:

```
WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(TheImage);
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
wBitmap.SaveJpeg(mStream, TheImage.DecodePixelWidth, TheImage.DecodePixelHeight, 0, 100);
mStream.Read(ByteArray, 0, (int)mStream.Length);
```

Comment: I tried it but i have ArgumentException in wBitmap.SaveJpeg(mStream, TheImage.DecodePixelWidth, TheImage.DecodePixelHeight, 0, 100);